# how to send app to AppStore for approval, if it depends on others interaction

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

I have an app similar to ordering a taxi. It depends on somebody else answering to users request. How should I submit it to apple, given the fact that the response functionality can not be seen unless there is somebody in front of a computer to answer the request. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put information such as this in the App's "Reviewer Notes" section when you upload your App binary in [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) to explain to Apple what they will need to do and/or what they will or will not be able to test themselves.